# How to prevent Google Spreadsheets from translating function names?

Tags: google-sheets, localization, google-sheets-formula

A colleague who has a French-language system, and myself (using an English language system) collaborate on a google sheet.

When I copy this formula (in this example from B5 to B6):

```
=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN();4);"1";"") & ROW() - 1)
-if(ecritures!$H5=B$1;ecritures!$K5;0)+if(ecritures!$I5=B$1;ecritures!$K5;0)
```

Upon pasting, Google Sheets changes COLUMN() to COLONNE() (which is the French word for "Column"), causing:

```
=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;COLONNE();4);"1";"") & ROW() - 1)
-IF(ecritures!$H6=B$1;ecritures!$K6;0)+IF(ecritures!$I6=B$1;ecritures!$K6;0)
```

This causes B6 to display: #NAME (Unknown function: 'COLONNE'.)

Is there a way to paste a formula from one cell to another while preventing Google Sheets from trying to translate function names?

[image]

Comment: You have to set Google Sheets to only use formulas in English

Comment: @AAA I cannot find where to do this. In Spreadsheet Settings, there is only Locale, Timezone and Display Langue. The latter does not work (see responses below); and I don't want to mess with dates and currencies which work fine as it is, only function names.

Comment: check my answer below, especially the [Google Link](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), under "Change the language for functions"

Answer (score 1):

You have to set Google Sheets to only use formulas in English [[1](https://www.bettercloud.com/monitor/the-academy/using-formulas-in-different-languages-in-google-sheets/)]:

- On your Sheet, go to File.
- Select Spreadsheet settings.
- In the new
  window, select the option that reads “Always use the names of the
  functions in English.

You have Google's own answer [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):

Comment: I opened up Spreadsheet settings, then had to select a locale (for example Canada (French)), but none was selected by default. In my case selecting Canada (French) fixed my issue. However it says that the locale also affects the number formatting and the currency, so be careful!

Answer (score 1):

This issue is not affiliated with **Locale** but **Display Language** which can be also found in Spreadsheet settings:

[image: 0]

Comment: Perhaps, however the display language is unique to a user and applies to all Google products, according to the page that appears when you try to change the display language. The whole idea of translating function names seems wrong, in any event.

Answer (score 1):

Google added the option to always use English function names. Under File > Settings, check "Always use English function names", or something to the like, at the bottom of the page.